# Displaying scrape to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, rake, screen-scraping

I have a scrape I want to put onto the view, my rake file looks like this.

```
    desc "Fetch teams table"
    task :fetch_teams => :environment do
      require 'nokogiri'
      require 'open-uri'

      url = "http://www.nba.com/standings/team_record_comparison/conferenceNew_Std_Cnf.html"
      doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
      puts doc.css("tr.title:has(td:contains('Western')) ~tr").map {|a| a.search('td')[0].text}
    end
```

I have also Defined this in my controller

```
      def show
      @teams = []
        doc.css("tr.title:has").each do |team|
      @teams << item.at_css("td:contains('Western') ~tr").text
    end
```

But

```
  <% if @teams %>
    <ul>
      <% @teams.each do |team| %>
        <li><%= team %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
```

Wont work?

why?

Thanks

Comment: In your controller, `@teams = []` means `@teams` is not nil anymore, so testing `if @teams` will always returns true, even if `@teams` is an empty array. Use `if @teams.present?` to test both if it is not nil AND if it is NOT empty ;-) (`.blank?` method is the exact opposite of `.present?`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the controller

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
@teams = []
url = "http://www.nba.com/standings/team_record_comparison/conferenceNew_Std_Cnf.html"
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
doc.css("tr.title:has(td:contains('Western')) ~tr").each do |team|
  p team.search('td')[0].text
  @teams << team.search('td')[0].text
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're building your Nokigiri `doc` in a rake task, then you don't have access to that `doc` inside your controller.  What exactly is `doc` pointing to in your controller action?